# How to bind in Codebehind from a global variable in App class in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, prism

I'm trying to  create an NavigationPage  TitleView with traditional Cart Icon saying (3) Items etc.
So the global CartCount variable is Declared in App class.
My *CommonToolbarPage*  class Lays out the top of all 50 pages with Logo, search button and Cart icon like every shop on the internet. I'm using Prism.

What  I'm after is what goes here to  bind to CartCount so BadgeText updates when the CartCount updates.

```
BadgeText = App.CartCount , // Jiberish
```

Cut down class

```
public class CommonToolbarPage : ContentPage
{

    public CommonToolbarPage()
    {
        //NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        ShowDefaultTitle();
      //this.BindingContext=  new CommonToolbarPageViewModel(navigationService);

    }


    private void ShowDefaultTitle()
    {
        


        SfButton sfButton = new SfButton
        {
            CornerRadius = 4,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["IconButtonStyle"],
            Text = (String)Application.Current.Resources["Cart"],
            FontFamily = "UIFontIcons",
            TextColor = Color.White,

            // Command = new Command(GoCart)
        };

        var Endlayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,

        };

        var imSfBadgeView = new SfBadgeView
        {
          
            BadgeText = App.Cart, // Jiberish 
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 0),
            Padding = new Thickness(0),
            WidthRequest = 40,
            // Content = sfButton,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            BadgeSettings = new BadgeSetting
            {
                BackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PrimaryColor"],
                BadgeType = BadgeType.None,
                FontSize = 10,
                Stroke = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["Gray-White"],
                StrokeWidth = 1,
                Offset = new Point(-10, 10)
            }
        };
        Endlayout.Children.Add(imSfBadgeView);
       


         NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, Endlayout);
    }

   
}
```

Each  page then looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local1:CommonToolbarPage  xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:blaAppV1.Views.Templates" 
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:listview="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.ListView.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:blaAppV1.Views;assembly=blaAppV1"
x:Class="blaAppV1.Views.Home">


  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Label Text="Home" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Button Text="Appliances" Command="{Binding Path=NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="Appliances" />
</StackLayout>
```

</local1:CommonToolbarPage>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use `SetBinding` to create a binding in code

```
myLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "CartCount");
myLabel.BindingContext = App;
```

Comment: `nameof( App.CartCount )` please (instead of the magic string)